# .netCore 3.0 Dark theme text color is not applied correctly

Tags: css, asp.net-core-mvc

I am attempting to update my site to use a dark mode. The functionality seems to work, but only part of it. The Text-color is not updating until I toggle it on the chrome console, same with Microsoft edge. Not sure why. I have applied the !important tag in the CSS file, but that doesn't change the outcome.

This is an MVC app using .netCore 3.0, I do not know what I am doing as I only really do backend development.

The expected results should be that the text correctly applies with the toggle. Currently, does not apply until I toggle in debug console. All other color changes do apply.
I have the following in my css file

```
[data-theme="dark"] {
    --primary-color: #9A97F3;
    --secondary-color: #818cab;
    --font-color: #e1e1ff !important;
    --bg-color: #161625;
    --heading-color: #818cab;
}
```

with the following logic to apply the change

```
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');

    function switchTheme(e) {
        if (e.target.checked) {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
        }
        else {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
        }
    }
    
    toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);
    
    function switchTheme(e) {
        if (e.target.checked) {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
            localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark'); //add this
        }
        else {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
            localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light'); //add this
        }
    }
    
    const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') ? localStorage.getItem('theme') : null;
    
    if (currentTheme) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', currentTheme);
    
        if (currentTheme === 'dark') {
            toggleSwitch.checked = true;
        }
    }
```

-edit, fixed code format

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo to change theme with buttons:

css:

```
<style>
.dark-mode {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }

    .light-mode {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
    }
</style>
```

Html:

```
<h3>Test</h3>
<button onclick="darkMode()">Darkmode</button>
<button onclick="lightMode()">LightMode</button>
```

js:

```
function darkMode() {
            var element = document.body;
            element.className = "dark-mode";
        }
        function lightMode() {
            var element = document.body;
            element.className = "light-mode";
        }
```

result:
[image]